# Custom FolderBrowserDialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

I need to do a window that will show the user all the subfolders inside a concrete folder (in the same way than the FolderBrowserDialog does for WinForms), but I want to add some logic to let the user mark as undesired any folders.

These undesired folders will contain a forbidden icon instead of a folder icon, and won't be shown the subfolders of these folders.

So my problem is that I need to implement a FolderBrowserDialog + some logic that will affect the icons of the folders. Any idea of how can I do this?

Comment: It takes a TreeView and a week or two of your time.  Good luck with it.

Comment: *Any idea of how can I do this?* Yes, but that's not what this website is for. It's to help with *specific* programming problems, so why don't you have a go at implementing your requirements and then come back if and when you get stuck on a particular problem. It's really not too difficult to work out how to replicate a `FolderBrowserDialog`. Start by calling `Directory.GetFiles` and then finish with the `TreeView` that Hans suggested to display your files/folders. Of course, you'll need a `DataTemplate` to define your folder icons, etc. too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few approaches to this, but just like Hans has suggested, `TreeView` is probably going to play a big part in this... that is, of course, depending on how you lay things out.  Anyways, it appears that you need a bump in the right direction, so I'll suggest these two open source projects:

**OpenFileOrFolderDialog**: https://github.com/scottwis/OpenFileOrFolderDialog

**VistaFolderBrowserDialog** (scroll down to see it): http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/

Review their code, see how things are structured.  This will give you a basic understanding of what choices you should make during your development process.

Furthermore, [this very comprehensive article](http://www.ssware.com/articles/folderbrowserdialog-unmasked-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-folder-browser-component-from-dotnet-framework.htm) on `FolderBrowserDialog` implementation will assist you in making your design decisions.

Good luck!